# How can I get apt-get to install python packages for a different version of python?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, python, aptitude

In Ubuntu 10.10, I have installed python 2.7.  I would like to use apt-get to install packages to this version of python but I haven't been able to figure out how.

Things I have tried without success:

changing the symlink at /usr/bin/python to point to /usr/bin/python2.7 - even after doing this apt-get still installs stuff to python2.6.

Set up python2.7 as the primary alternative using update-alternatives - doesn't work.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Did you install python 2.7 with apt-get?

Comment: yes, I installed python 2.7 with apt-get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set of currently supported python versions can be found in `/usr/share/python/debian_defaults`. Check whenever `python-2.7` is listed there as supported.

There is a so-called `python-support` system in Debian. When `python-support`-aware package (i.e., when maintainer used `python-support` stuff while packaging) says that it [supports specific range of Python versions](http://www.debian.org/doc/packaging-manuals/python-policy/ch-module_packages.html#s-specifying_versions), dpkg calls [hooks for updates to installed runtimes](http://www.debian.org/doc/packaging-manuals/python-policy/ch-python.html#s-runtimes_hooks) as a part of `postinst` process. There's also alternative `python-central` system, which does the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered the Python [setuptools](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/EasyInstall)? After you install it, installing additional packages is typically as easy as:

```
$ easy_install package-name
```

(depending on how you installed python 2.7, you might need to use `sudo`)

Comment: Yes, I have setuptools working with virtualenv right now.  The original question is basically a matter of curiousity now.  I guess apt-get is only set up to modify the system install of python?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a problem from the repository?
You should send a bugreport to ubuntu no?
Otherwise you can install it by hand where you want :-) (but of course it's more tricky than apt-get foo)

Comment: the repository seems to be fine to me - what I was trying to do was install the updates to a different version of python.